# xkb and Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: gnome, keyboard-layout, wayland, 20.10, xkb

I like to customize my keyboard layout and I usually use a modified `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us` file to get what I want. Since Ubuntu 20.04 and now with 20.10 my modifications are not taken into account anymore. But, surprisingly, when viewing the keyboard layout in `settings->Region and Language->Input Sources` the modified layout is displayed. Are extra steps needed to make the custom layout work?
I use Gnome Shell and Wayland.

In `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us` I added:

```
xkb_symbols "basic" {
...
    key <AC10> {
        type="MY_CONTROL_LEVEL3",
        symbols[Group1]= [ semicolon, colon, asciicircum ]
    };
    key <AC11> {
        type="MY_CONTROL_LEVEL3",
        symbols[Group1]= [ apostrophe,  quotedbl, mu ]
    };
    key <BKSP> {
        type="MY_CONTROL_LEVEL3",
        symbols[Group1]= [ BackSpace, Delete, Delete ]
    };
    key <AB08> {
        type="MY_CONTROL_LEVEL3",
        symbols[Group1]= [  comma,   less,  underscore ]
    };
    key <SPCE> {
        type="MY_CONTROL_LEVEL3",
        symbols[Group1]= [ space, space, paragraph ]
    };

...
};
```

I have made a file `my-us` with:

```
// Allow Shift and Control modifiers
partial default xkb_types "default" {
    type "MY_CONTROL_LEVEL3" {
        modifiers = Shift+Control;
        map[Shift] = Level2;
        map[Control] = Level3;
        level_name[Level1] = "Base";
        level_name[Level2] = "Shift";
        level_name[Level3] = "Control";
    };
};
```

This is a screenshot from the settings app:

[image: keyboard layout in settings]

`xkbmap -print` gives:

````
        xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
        xkb_types     { include "complete"      };
        xkb_compat    { include "complete"      };
        xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us+inet(evdev)"     };
        xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)"     };
};```
````

Comment: In 20.04 GNOME and Wayland same setup worked?

Comment: @UnKNOWn no, it didn't work on 20.04 either.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson The modifications are under `xkb_symbols "basic"`. Thanks anyway.

Comment: does it work with `setxkbmap us` ? what is the ouput of `setxkbmap -print`

Comment: @MarceloAvila `setxkbmap us` doesn't work. I added the output from `xkbmap -print` to my original post.

Comment: hum.. strange indeed. I would suggest checking if it works in a X11 session.

Comment: what is the output of `setxkbmap -query | grep layout`

Comment: @MarceloAvila the command gives `layout: us`

Answer (score 0):

I partially worked around my problem by using the Alacritty terminal emulator which allows to define keyboard mappings at the terminal level.

Recently, after upgrading to Ubuntu 21.10 and switching back to X11 my settings are active again for all applications.

Answer (score -1):

Please try `Alt-F2` & then in the pop-up enter single character `r` & then submit. This would restart Gnome.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. It doesn't work, even after rebooting the changes are not effective.